# How to parse a fixed width file using Java?

Tags: java, parsing

I am working on a small project, and it's mostly working out. The whole purpose is to take a file loop through it, and each individual line gets delimited in some manner. I've done that for commas, pipes, etc, but I also need to do a fixed width version. I wrote the code below, which should take find all the elements on the line isolate only the ones with a string value, and add it to an arrayList.

Right now it adds the first value, and then a series of commas to represent the whitespace, but it never gets to the 2nd string value.

```
public static List fwListCreator(String str) throws IOException {

 List<String> fixedWidthList = new ArrayList<String>();
  char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
    List<List<Boolean>> zeroWhite = new ArrayList<>();
    
    zeroWhite.add(new ArrayList<Boolean>()); 
    List<Boolean> temp = zeroWhite.get(0);

    //add all non-whitespace character from string
    for (char ch : charArray) {
         temp.add(!Character.isWhitespace(ch)); 
    }
    
    System.out.println(temp);

     //get all nonwhitespace characters per column

    int maxLine = zeroWhite.stream().mapToInt(e -> e.size()).max().orElse(0);
    System.out.println(maxLine);

     //max number of characters in row.
    int[] charCountArray = new int[maxLine];
    //counting all non-whitespace per column
    for (List<Boolean> row : zeroWhite) {
        for (int columnChars = 0; columnChars < row.size(); ++columnChars) {
            if (row.get(columnChars)) {
                ++charCountArray[columnChars];
            }
        }
    }
    //overview of non-white columns
    Map<Integer, Long> potentialMap = (Map<Integer, Long>) Arrays.stream(charCountArray).mapToObj(i -> (Integer)i).collect(Collectors.groupingBy( Function.identity(), // their identity (value)
                 Collectors.counting()));

    //minimum number of non-whitespace columns
    int emptyIntVal = Collections.min(potentialMap.keySet());
    //find delimited columns
    List<Boolean> emptyListVal= Arrays.stream(charCountArray).mapToObj(n -> n == emptyIntVal).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    List<Integer> valIndices = new ArrayList<>();
    
    for (int charCount = 0; charCount < maxLine; ++charCount) {
        if (emptyListVal.get(charCount)) {
            valIndices.add(charCount);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(valIndices);
    
    int indexSizeVal = valIndices.size();
    valIndices.add(0,0);
  
     int len = str.length();
     //parse
     for (int i = 1; i <= indexSizeVal; ++i) {
         if (len < valIndices.get(i)) break;
                
         fixedWidthList.add(str.substring(valIndices.get(i-1), valIndices.get(i)).trim()); 

         }
return fixedWidthList

 }
```

These are the 3 lines being passed in the file, 1 each time so str represents 1 of these lines at a time.

```
 Ackerman        Scott
 Jones           Steve
 Gaiman          Neil
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is this str? and make your code more readable by commenting maybe? Atleast add a method signature to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for? I don't have any idea what your data source is so I just used a `String[][]`

```
public static String format(String[][] columns){
    int[] maxSize = new int[columns[0].length];
    for (int i = 0; i < maxSize.length; i++) {
        int max = 0;
        for (String[] column : columns) {
            max = Math.max(max, column[i].length());
        }
        maxSize[i] = max;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String[] column : columns) {
        for (int i = 0; i < column.length; i++) {
            sb.append(String.format("%-" + maxSize[i] + "s", column[i]));
        }
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```